# work only default controller in linux host

Tags: linux, codeigniter, controller

i have a project that is running in windows host . now i wanna to change my host to linux host. 
the problem is : server only show my default controller and other url or controller cant loaded.

the message is:
Not Found
The requested URL /padash/login/personel was not found on this server.

my htaccess config is:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /padash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

//************/////

note:both of my host are in my local computers

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because Windows is not a case-sensitive system while Linux is. Please make sure you follow these rules.

Naming Conventions

1. File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php
2. Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: `class Myclass`
3. Class names and file names must match.

Comment: all rules checked.but its not ok;